# LINQ to entities does not recognize the method 'System.DecimalToDecimal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

A table called "Player" is read as an object, which has 'BattingAverage' column. I would like to allow the user to search a specific player by a range of min average and max average that user input.
I wrote as Lamda (I also tried to add **AsEnumerable()** after 'player.BattingAverage')

```
dbcontext.Players.Where(player => player.BattingAverage >= Convert.ToDecimal(txtMin.Text) ||
        player.BattingAverage <= Convert.ToDecimal(txtMax.Text))
        .OrderBy(player => player.PlayerID).Load();
```

and normal query

```
decimal test;
test = Convert.ToDecimal(txtMin.Text) + 4.5m;
txtMax.Text = test.ToString();

var query = from player in dbcontext.Players
            where player.BattingAverage >= Convert.ToDecimal(txtMin.Text) ||
                            player.BattingAverage <= Convert.ToDecimal(txtMax.Text)
            select player;

playerBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
playerBindingSource.MoveFirst();
```

but both I got an error that it says:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.DecimalToDecimal(System.Object)' method and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression.

The original table's BattingAverage column value is decimal(3,3)

I also tried

```
decimal test;
test = Convert.ToDecimal(txtMin.Text) + 4.5m;
txtMax.Text = test.ToString();
```

and it worked, so I assume that the problem is in the LINQ.

Comment: The message is pretty self-explanatory. LINQ to entities has to be able to translate your query into SQL. That limits the things you can do. It can't turn any arbitrary function into SQL. The solution is that you'd have to do it in two steps. First get the data (use `ToList` to materialize the results, for example) and then perform whatever transformations you need. Or in your case, you can just do the conversion first, so it's not part of the database query.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I got your point:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the converts outside of your query:

```
var min=Convert.ToDecimal(txtMin.Text);
var max =Convert.ToDecimal(txtMax.Text);

 var query = from player in dbcontext.Players
             where player.BattingAverage >= min && player.BattingAverage <= max
             select player;
```

Your Linq to Entities query is going to be translated to sql, but the linq provider is not capable to translate those method calls to a corresponding store function. You can find the list of supported methods in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The error disappeared, but it displays all the entries without filtering. I will keep on working the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just needed to change '||' to '&&'.
Thank you so much for you help:)